# Pandas: Not able to group by Index column

Tags: python, csv, numpy, pandas

I have a csv file that contains data in the following format.

```
Layer   time     BSs        Temp    Message
57986   2:52:46   87        None    CMSG 
20729   0:23:02   82        None    BMSG 
20729   0:44:17   81        None    AMSG 
20729   0:23:02   82        None    BMSG 
20729   0:44:17   81        None    AMSG
```

I read the csv file into a pandas data frame as shown below.

```
with open(INPUT_FILE) as fin:
    df = pd.read_csv(INPUT_FILE,
                  index_col=["Layer","time"],
                  usecols=["Layer", "time", "BSs",,"Message"],
                  header=0,
                  #names=["Layer", "time", "BSs", ,"Message"])
    gb = df.groupby(['Layer'])

    for k in gb:
         print('key = {}'.format(k))
```

I am getting the error

```
KeyError: 'Layer'
```

Also I want to remove duplicate row from the above dataframe.

```
df = df.drop_duplicates()
```

doesn't seem to do it correctly.It is removing way too many rows for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

As `Layer` is in the index, it is not an available column on which to group.  You must first reset your index.

```
df = pd.read_csv(INPUT_FILE,
                 usecols=["Layer", "relative_time", "BSs", "Vge","Message"],
                 header=0).drop_duplicates()

gb = df.groupby('Layer')

for k in gb:
    print('key = {}'.format(k))

key = (20729,    Layer relative_time      Ht  BSs   Vge  Temp Message
1  20729       0:23:02  45.06m   82  11.6  None    BMSG
2  20729       0:44:17  45.06m   81  11.6  None    AMSG)
key = (57986,    Layer relative_time     Ht  BSs   Vge  Temp Message
0  57986       2:52:46  0.00m   87  15.4  None    CMSG)
```

Comment: What about drop_duplicates() function? It doesn't seem to work as I expect it to?

Comment: But I think it is dropping too many duplicates. duplicate row would have the same `Layer` + `relative_time`

Comment: You need to better describe the problem and your expected results.